# How to set root/base url for a laravel-vujs project?

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-router, vuex

I've deployed a VueJS project to a domain like `www.example.com/demos/app,`

But when I send a request to api from axios it is pointing to `www.example.com/login` instead of `www.example.com/demos/app/login`

Here is my request code using `axios`

```
export const login = ({ dispatch }, { payload, context }) => {
    return axios.post('/login', payload).then((response) => {
        // do something
    }).catch((error) => {
        // handle erros
    })
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way you could go about this is to add a meta tag to the head of your page (like you may do with the csrf) and then reference it in your `bootstrap.js` file:

**head**

```
<meta name="api-base-url" content="{{ url('demos/app') }}" />
```

**bootstrap.js** (underneath `window.axios = require('axios');`)

```
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="api-base-url"]').content;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: document.head.querySelector('meta[name="api-base-url"]').content; this will cause problem during tests (vue testing),

Comment: @EmekaMbah Does this question solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820828/during-testing-a-vue-component-in-jest-document-queryselector-always-returns-nul?

Answer (score 5):

In config.js:

```
const CONFIG = {
  API_URL_ROOT: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/',
}

export default CONFIG;
```

You can set axios default like this:

```
import config from '../config.js';

axios.create({
  baseURL: config.API_BASE_URL
});
```

Or you can just set path by importing `API_BASE_URL` from `config` and then point it each time you make a `get/post/put/delete` call using `axios`

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by config.js

Comment: You can keep a config file where you store all sort of configurations and images import it in places necessary

Comment: Awesome Solution

Comment: I prefer to go with this solution, the solution by @Rwd causes issue during test, since document.head.querySelector('meta[name="api-base-url"]').content; is not available.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel ships with axios and its imported in `bootstrap.js`, so simply go to `bootstrap.js` and add this:

```
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://example.test';
```

You can add this after `window.axios.defaults.headers.common` line


-Additional information:

`axios.create` will make an instance that has its own global url and configurations. use this if you have multiple urls or configuration and you want to use it in different components.

Answer (score 0):

Create `vue.config.js` in Project root directory( if not exist ) -

In `vue.config.js` -

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? '/demos/app/'
        : '/'
}
```

Then, Add the line in `resources/js/bootstrap.js` -

```
const {publicPath} = require("../../vue.config");
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = publicPath
```

Answer (score 0):

.env

```
MIX_APP_URL="${APP_URL}"
```

resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.MIX_APP_URL;
```

Update your APP_URL in **.env** file and add the above code on respective files.