# vue-test-utils returns null for document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I am writing unit tests for a Vue.js component that displays some radiobuttons and emits an event with the radio button id whenever a button is checked:

**ApplicationElement.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div id="element">
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="Element"
        id="element1"
        v-on:change="chooseElement"
      />
      Element1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="Element"
        id="element2"
        v-on:change="chooseElement"
      />
      Element2
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="Element"
        id="element3"
        v-on:change="chooseElement"
      />
      Element3
    </label>
    <label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="Element"
        id="element4"
        v-on:change="chooseElement"
      />
      Element4
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    chooseElement () {
      var chosenElement = document.querySelector('input[name="Element"]:checked').id
      this.$emit('passChosenElement', {category: chosenElement})
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I wrote the following test for said component:

**ApplicationElement.spec.js:**

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import ApplicationElement from '@/components/ApplicationElement.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

describe('ApplicationElement tests', () => {
    it('should emit event with element1 parameter on corresponding radio button choice', async() => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(ApplicationElement, {
            localVue,
            attachTo: document.body,
            propsData: {
                recursionNumber: 1
            }
        })
        await wrapper.find('input[type="radio"][id="element1"]').setChecked()
        expect(wrapper.emitted().passChosenElement[0]).toEqual([{element: 'element1'}])
        wrapper.destroy()
    })
})
```

The test fails with: **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"**
If I remove the *document.querySelector* line from the chooseElement method in the component and emit the right id by hand, the test succeeds.

How can I get *document.querySelector* to work with vue-test-utils?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know, this question is already a bit older, but I finally found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49821140). You need to attach your component with `attachTo` (since May 2021) to an html element. The solution looks like this:

```js
describe('ApplicationElement tests', () => {
  it('should emit event with element1 parameter on corresponding radio button choice', async() => {
      const elem = document.createElement('div')
      if (document.body) {
         document.body.appendChild(elem)
      }

      const wrapper = shallowMount(ApplicationElement, {
          localVue,
          propsData: {
              recursionNumber: 1
          },
          attachTo: elem,
      })
      await wrapper.find('input[type="radio"][id="element1"]').setChecked()
      expect(wrapper.emitted().passChosenElement[0]).toEqual([{element: 'element1'}])
      wrapper.destroy()
  })
});
```

As you already did, it is important to call `wrapper.destroy()` after each test. Little refactoring tip: Put `wrapper.destroy()` into an `afterEach` callback function. Here you can find more about [attachTo](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument).

Comment: You are using `attachTo` twice in the same object. Could you remove the incorrect one?

Comment: Thank u for the hint @DrikusRoor. I removed it.